# How do I resize views when keyboard pops up using Auto Layout

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a view (a `UITableView` in this case, but that's not important) on my `UIViewController` that I want to have the height resized when the keyboard pops up.

What is the best way to do this in Auto Layout? Currently on the view I have these constraints:

- Top space to superview: 0
- Trailing space to superview: 0
- Leading space to superview: 0
- Bottom space to superview: 0
- <s>Height equals = 424</s>

I think the quickest way of doing this, is to remove the height and bottom space constraint and just resize the actual view in the code when `keyboardDidAppear` notification is called, but is there any other ways to do this?

EDIT: I removed the height constraint, my bad.

Comment: it may be better to update the `contentInset` property instead of playing with changing the actual layout in that case.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would give you a generic idea, it may need to be re-adjusted for your actual project.

## swift 4.2

```
let notificationTokenKeyboardWillAppear = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (note) in
    guard let keyboardFrame = (note.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else { return }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: CATransaction.animationDuration(), animations: {
        self.scrollView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0.0, left: 0.0, bottom: keyboardFrame.size.height, right: 0.0)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

and

```
let notificationTokenKeyboardWillHide = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { (_) in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: CATransaction.animationDuration(), animations: {
        self.scrollView?.contentInset = .zero
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

***NOTE-1:** `scrollView` represents here any subset of `UIScrollView`, e.g. `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`, etc...*

***NOTE-2:** you'll need to remove the tokens manually by invoking the [`removeObserver(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1413994-removeobserver) method when you are about to release the view and the closure-based observers are not necessary any longer*

---

## ObjC

I persume the `UITableView *_tableView` has been set up properly somewhere before.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // ...

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        id _obj = [note.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
        CGRect _keyboardFrame = CGRectNull;
        if ([_obj respondsToSelector:@selector(getValue:)]) [_obj getValue:&_keyboardFrame];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            [_tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, _keyboardFrame.size.height, 0.f)];
        } completion:nil];
    }];
    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f delay:0.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            [_tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
        } completion:nil];
     }];


     // ...
```

}

***NOTE:** if your* `UITableView` *is not at the bottom of the screen precisely, the* `contentInset` *value should be refined in this line:* `[_tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, 0.f, _keyboardFrame.size.height, 0.f)];`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, I will try this out. Is it generally not a good idea to resize views that has constraints? Is it better to use contentInset when we have constraints like this?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo, I think that resizing the view, just because of the keyboard appearance, is too inconvenient. on the other hand the `contentInset` propery and its behaviour are designed quite well for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works almost perfectly. The only thing I am not quite happy with is that half of the scroll bar is still hidden behind the keyboard, but the table view content is now visible above the keyboard. However I think this is still the best solution so far.

Comment: thanks for the nice solution! starred this question.

Comment: **NOTE:** also set scrollIndicatorInsets so that the scrollbar shifts correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Keep your height constraint and connect an outlet to it:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *CS_TableView_Height;
```

Take a look at Example 3 of [this tutorial](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/learn-to-love-auto-layout/).

Update your view's height by capturing keyboard event using `NSNotificationCenter`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // register for keyboard notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // unregister for keyboard notifications while not visible.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
}
```

You might want to also take a look at the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present) for some inspirations.

So in the end, you should get something like this:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow
{

    self.CS_TableView_Height.constant = 500;//For example

    [self.tableView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide
{

    self.CS_TableView_Height.constant = 568;// iPhone5 height

    [self.tableView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}
```

Comment: 1. the block-based notifications are much more convenient and better practice. 2. updating the `contentInset` property is also a much better practice.

Comment: @holex: could you please provide some code of your solution as an answer? :)

Comment: I will try this soon, but I think it's not a good idea to specify constant number as the height like this. Other keyboards like Japanese or Chinese might have different height than the English keyboard.

Comment: So you just need to get the keyboard's height and minus it dynamically

Comment: @NhonNguyen, yes, no problem, however I prefer give ideas only if I don't know the whole environment (like in this case).

Comment: also, you can change your selectors to keyboardWillShow: and keayboardWillHide: (with a colon), and then both your methods can receive a NSNotification object, where you can read the keyboard height from, so that you don't have to hard code it.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you shouldn't add a top-bottom constraint AND a height constraint. If the screen size changes, the app will crash (unless one of the constraints have lower priority, in which case it will be removed).

Secondly, in your keyboardDidAppear notification method, you just change the bottom space to superview's constant value and call `[myView setNeedsDisplay]`

Edit: You don't do the setNeedsDisplay after becomeFirstResponder. You add `self` as observer for `keyboardWillShow` / `keyboardWillHide` notifications, and in that method, you update the constraint and call `setNeedsDisplay`.

Take a look at [this apple post](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html), `Listing 5-1  Handling the keyboard notifications` and `Listing 5-2  Additional methods for tracking the active text field` provide the code.

Comment: Hey, thanks Lord Zsolt, but It seems like the view still does not resize after I called that. I've removed the height constraint too. I called `setNeedsDisplay` right after I called `becomeFirstResponder` to bring up the keyboard.